# Why doesn't Unity use gnome-panel?

Tags: unity, gnome-panel

I haven't been able to Google up any info on this: **Why doesn't Unity use gnome-panel?**

Unity's panel has no functionality that can't be implemented on top of gnome-panel (witness previous versions of Ubuntu Netbook). The new panel is missing a bunch of features (chiefly system monitors and a decent clock applet), and since gnome-panel applets aren't supported, we'll have to wait for entirely new stuff to be written--in an environment, I understand, that is too crippled to be able to design nice meters and such.

Comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1291/why-are-the-moderators-closing-posts/1295#1295

Comment: I don't see how this question fits the criteria for closure. It isn't a rant, it's a question that has a definite answer (I even put the question itself in bold so it's obvious). I asked why Unity no longer uses gnome-panel. "Why" is always a reasonable question. I couldn't find anything on Google about this. So it doesn't make sense to close it. Closing a rant is understandable. Closing a legitimate question isn't.

Comment: Unity doesn't, nor has it ever, used GNOME-Panel...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gnome-panel has first and foremost been abandoned by upstream Gnome. It has been replaced by gnome-shell, and is only meant as a backup for machines that can't run shell. See for instance [this mailinglist](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gnome-shell-list/2010-March/msg00100.html) post.

Hence it would not make sense for a downstream project such as Unity to be based on it. That would make it harder to keep up with future Gnome releases as gnome-panel will eventually be removed.

Comment: Thanks for giving an answer instead of claiming that this isn't a real question.

Comment: Actually, this is wrong. The gnome-panel was not abandoned, and multiple developers have made it public on the gnome-planet that it is still being developed and will live on for a while.

Comment: While abandoned might not be the best choice of words, it's clear that gnome-panel is not the focus of future Gnome design. While it's still developed as fallback mode, it's recommended to users that they should use Gnome Shell.

Comment: it's not the focus of the main desktop, but that does not mean that there is no focus on it. Not only are many users sticking with it, but so are many distributions. To claim that is is abandoned or no longer being focused on, is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

The whole idea of Unity is to be a compiz based desktop so there is no need for a gnome-panel. Unity still has to mature. It needs to grow on anyone and it currently lacks a good config tool (at least one for adding lenses to the launcher).
It works at the moment so that's good. But it needs a bit more attention.

Sidenote: System monitor and clock can be added as an 'indicator' so that might ease your problem.

By the way: your question tends to make this into a discussion.

Comment: The last line - +1.

Comment: @Roland Taylor: There was no need of making this into a discussion until people started voting to close this question for invalid reasons. The closure description says: "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form." Not a single one of those clauses applies. The question was very clearly formulated. It was in the subject line and repeated in bold in the question itself. It has a well-defined answer. I asked a question; somebody gave an answer. Why close it?

Comment: @mssever: I don't think you're understanding a few things here. Firstly, the people who answered cannot even see that this question has close votes. So your reasoning is not valid - they didn't know it was going to be closed for any reason. Secondly, the question is invalidated by the fact that unity has never used gnome-panel in the first place. Thirdly, asking a question like this can potentially lead to arguments, due to what it is related to. That would be like asking about "why banshee over rhythmbox?" People WILL start arguments in such cases.

Comment: @Roland Taylor: I never said or implied that Unity ever used gnome-panel; I asked why it doesn't use it (which is a valid question since the previous default UI did). Second, I never said or implied that the people answering this question could see the votes. However, you're one of the people who voted to close it, which is why I'm complaining to you. I wish people would read carefully before stifling questions. Nobody has argued over the reason for not using gnome-panel, so where's the beef? Or are you arguing for preemptive moderation, which would be unjustifiable?